# Is it time for a list of canonical questions?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

I notice that the "*How do I make an open-source licence that forbids commercial activity*" question came up again, as it does from time to time:

- [Open source license for limited use](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/open-source-license-for-limited-use)
- [Links to authoritative discussion of why not to add non-commercial clauses to otherwise free/open licenses?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/9415/458)
- [Copyleft license that explicitly disallows monetisation](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/9281/458)
- [Is Geogebra's "non-commercial only GPL3" license valid?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/8660/458) (to a lesser extent)
- [Open-source license to prevent commercial use?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/4875/458)

One fairly-common solution to recurrent questions on the SE network is the idea of the list of **canonical questions**, being those questions that naturally get asked again and again.  Instead of writing a new answer each time, or just closing each new question as duplicates of whichever previous example comes quickest out of a cursory site search, the idea of the canonical question is that the community tries hard to make the answer(s) on it as complete, up-to-date, and well-written as possible, and all repeats of the question are closed as duplicates of the canonical one.  This serves a double purpose: it makes selecting the duplicate a quicker and easier process, and ensures that the asker of the new question gets pointed to the best set of answers available on-site.

The list of canonical questions is usually maintained as a meta question/answer, with proposals for new inclusions being added as answers to that question, or as meta questions in their own right.  In case this is still unclear, a quick perusal of [ServerFault's canonical list](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/1986/55514) may clarify the process.

Is it time for OS.SE to start developing such a list?

Comment: Sounds good to me. I'm not sure we have many candidates for it right now, but the "open source but non-commercial" question is a good start. I'll see if I can start writing one.

Comment: Several questions are already being used as canonical questions. But you could be right that a new one for non-commercial would be better than any existing one.

Comment: I've [created a canonical question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/9805/98) for this topic.

Comment: The time to start making canonical questions was (checks watch) eleven years ago. *You haven't voted on questions for a while...* that's because they're not...um, one of the, approximately ten, questions on any given SE site that a user who's been here for half that long could find the dupe of. - ArtOfCode's question *on the main site*, where things can be directly closed as dupes of it, +1ed two days ago, and I don't UV questions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be support for this, so I have done so.  See [What are the canonical questions we've discovered?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/855/what-are-the-canonical-questions-weve-discovered) for more details, and thanks to ArtOfCode for the very first canonical answer!

The procedure for nominating further questions for canonicalisation (canonisation?) is described in the linked question (the canonical canonical question, if you like).